# How to tell Atom to not remember last opened project?

Tags: atom-editor

I would like to retrieve the welcome screen (and only it) when I start Atom. That way, I'll be able to choose the project I want to work on each time I start Atom (currently, I have to close the project opened the last time).

I already re-enabled the Welcome package in the `init.coffee` file so I see the welcome screen each time I start Atom, but there are two problems.

First: this screen is now shown every time I open a new window, so every time I open another project than the current one (I use Projects Manager if it matters). It's not very useful, as I only want to see this screen when I start Atom.

Second: I see the welcome screen on start, but only as new tabs in the last opened project, so the problem remains the same.

Has someone a solution?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same issue - settings are correctly set to "open empty editor on start" and "restore previous windows on start = no" - however Atom always restores previous windows with previous files. Uninstalled and re-installed today, same issue.

Answer (score 6):

The setting you are looking for is *Settings > Open Empty Editor On Start*, which is on the *Core Settings* page, right under *Ignored Names*. Make sure to enable this setting, i.e. check the box. Whenever you start Atom from its icon now, it will start with an empty editor, and will not reopen your previously used files.

[image: Atom Settings]

Comment: I already tried this option and, currently, it's checked since a few days, but Atom still opens the last opened files. Do you think there's anything I can do wrong? I tried to disable Projects Manager, but it doesn't change anything…

Comment: I tried this setting locally and it worked as expected for me. Do you have any other packages installed that could interfere with this?

Comment: Wow, that's weird. I just tried by disabling all packages, it doesn't change anything. If it comes from a package, I think it could be open-recent or project-manager. Should I try to completely uninstall them?

Comment: Well, open-recent sounds like a possible candidate. I have project-manager myself and I don't think it does anything in this area...

Comment: Just uninstalled open-recent, and Atom still opens last files. I noticed that checking or unchecking the "open empty editor" option does not modify the `config.cson` file. Is it normal?

Comment: When disabling the setting, it adds the following entry in `config.cson` for me: `openEmptyEditorOnStart: false`

Comment: It doesn't change anything if I manually set this property on `true`. :/ I think I'll reinstall Atom and see if the setting works on a new install, maybe something is broken…

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem, too.

But I found that if I had **'openEmptyEditorOnStart: true'** in the config.cson file, and each time I quit the Atom I did "**Remove Project Folder**" in the "**Tree View**", next time I opened the Atom edit, I can open it without the last opened project.

Hope it helps. :)

[image]

Comment: In fact it works, but it's not perfect, as it's still not automatic (we have to do this trick every time). I hope we'll have a working setting one day…

Answer (score 1):

Proper configuration to get empty editor on every start:

✔️ Open Empty Editor On Start

✖️ Restore Previous Windows On Start

Comment: Still doesn't work. Atom really, REALLY likes to reopen projects.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Atom / File > Reopen Project > Clear Project History]

Just go to *File* > *Reopen Project* > *Clear Project History*. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched of package tree view
Setting/packages tree-view - disable
And when open Atom it is free of project tree

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can add screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do both in Core settings:

- check **Open Empty Editor On Start**
- set **Restore Previous Windows On Start** to no
  [image]